# Classic BPF -- simple stats not available?

Tags: filter, bpf

I was playing with the classic `BPF` to filter something on a `netlink` socket and found that there's no simple stats available to verify if the packet has been dropped or allowed.

So I looked at https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/core/filter.c#L90 and yes, it executes the filter bpf program but does not update anything that would tell me in the user space (via /proc FS for instance) whether the filter has dropped a packet or not. This would simplify the debugging of cBPF filters.

Is it expected, or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you're right, there are no statistics associated with BPF programs attached to sockets. If you want such statistics, **you'll have to compute them yourself, with a eBPF program and a map**.

As far as I know, the XDP hook is the only hook that comes with statistics (through ethtool).